# How to insert dynamically cloned elements to mysql database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have website that enables user to select favourite websites, date of visiting the website, comments like how satisfied with the website they visited on that day. Initially there are four rows are hard coded and inserted into the mysql database. Then there is a add button enabling user to choose more website to add onto the existing ones, and also associated date of visiting and comments. The question is how can I insert the additional selected fav website into database.

Here is my code [jsfiddle.net/j8odptds/](http://jsfiddle.net/j8odptds/)

```
         var cloneIndex = $('#websites').length+4;  
         $('#add').on('click', function() {
          var newElem = $('#websites').clone().appendTo('#addMoreWebsite').attr('id','website' + cloneIndex);
          $(newElem).find('[id=website4]').attr('name','website' + (cloneIndex));
          $(newElem).find('[id=website4]').attr('id','website' + (cloneIndex));

          $(newElem).find('[id=Date4]').attr('name','Date' + (cloneIndex));
          $(newElem).find('[id=Date4]').attr('id','Date' + (cloneIndex));

          $(newElem).find('[id=Comments4]').attr('name','Comments' + (cloneIndex));
          $(newElem).find('[id=Comments4]').attr('id','Comments' + (cloneIndex));

            cloneIndex++; 
        });
     <div class="well">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-3">
                 <h4>Favourite web</h4>
             </div>
             <div class="col-xs-2">
                 <h4>Date of visit</h4>
             </div>
             <div class="col-xs-3">
                   <h4>Comments</h4>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-3">
        <select class="form-control input-sm" name="website1" id="website1">
        <option>google</option>
        <option>msn</option>
        <option>youtube</option>
        <option>linkedin</option>
        <option>facebook</option>
        <option>skyscanners</option>
        <option>stackoverflow</option>
       </select> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
      <input class="form-control input-sm" type="date" name="Date">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
      <textarea class="form-control input-sm" rows="3" name="Comments">             </textarea>
  </div>
<br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <select class="form-control input-sm" name="website2" id="website2">
      <option>google</option>
        <option>msn</option>
        <option>youtube</option>
        <option>linkedin</option>
        <option>facebook</option>
        <option>skyscanners</option>
        <option>stackoverflow</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <input class="form-control input-sm" type="date" name="Date2" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <textarea class="form-control input-sm" rows="3" name="Comments2"></textarea>
  </div>
<br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <select class="form-control input-sm" name="website3" id="website3">
        <option>google</option>
        <option>msn</option>
        <option>youtube</option>
        <option>linkedin</option>
        <option>facebook</option>
        <option>skyscanners</option>
        <option>stackoverflow</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <input class="form-control input-sm" type="date" name="Date3" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <textarea class="form-control input-sm" rows="3" name="Comments3"></textarea>
  </div>
 <br>
<div class="row" id="websites">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <select class="form-control input-sm" name="website4" id="website4">
        <option>google</option>
        <option>msn</option>
        <option>youtube</option>
        <option>linkedin</option>
        <option>facebook</option>
        <option>skyscanners</option>
        <option>stackoverflow</option>
    </select>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <input class="form-control input-sm" type="date" name="Date4" id="Date4" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <textarea class="form-control input-sm" rows="3" name="Comments4" id="Comments4"></textarea>
  </div>
</div> 
 <div id="addMoreWebsite"></div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="add"       id="add">Add more Website</button>
```

Comment: Am I the only one not getting this question? :) Are You asking for User Interface help (How and when should it save)? Or strictly technical (how to save data from JS/HTML via PHP in MySQL for exapmle) ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the question is every time the page appears, the user can  choose four favourite websites without clicking "add more Website" button. However some users will have more favourite websites, then they can click on the add button to add more favourite websites, say website5,website6,website7 and so on, I can store the first 4 favourite websites, however how can I store the website5,6 and 7 into mysql database

Comment: In my opinion Relation is an answers here. You have table User and table Website. Make table User_favorite_website where You will store user_id and website_id  (it can include fields COMMENT and more as well). This way one user will be able to have more than 4 websites.

For purpose of joing data from this tables You will have to use MySQL syntax : JOIN 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: @Mr.TK thank you for you advise, I will go through this tutorial for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass all values to PHP as array. So all your inputs must have `name="namespace[rowId]name"`. And in PHP you just loop that array and insert all values to database.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text" name="Website[0]name"/>
    <select name="Website[0]rating"><option></option></select>
</div>

<button type="button" onClick="addRow()">Add row</button>

var lastRow = 0;
function addRow() {
    lastRow++;
    $('.wrappper').append(
        '<input type="text" name="Website[' + lastRow + ']name"/>'
        + '<select name="Website[' + lastRow + ']rating"><option></option></select>'
    );
}

[php]
foreach ($_POST['Website'] as $website) {
    $this->db->insert(array(
        'name' => $website['name'],
        'rating' => $website['rating'],
    ));
}
```

Comment: thanks a mill for your help, I see now I need to make array for php to loop through for the additional elements, and then insert to database, I am gonna try it now.